# How can I use duration() on local moment instance?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, momentjs

According to [moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) you could create a local instance of moment to format a date using other locale than is globally set.

That works fine with format(), but how can I use duration() on a local instance ?

Here is what I tried:

```
moment.locale('en');
var localMoment = moment("2015-03-12");
localMoment.locale('de');

// format date:
moment("2015-03-12").format("LL");        // "March 12, 2015"
localMoment.format("LL");                 // "12. März 2015"

// format duration:
moment.duration(3600000).humanize();      // "an hour"
localMoment.duration(3600000).humanize(); // TypeError: localMoment.duration is not a function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you cannot using `localMoment`.

A moment object returned by a called to `moment()` does not have a `duration` function (whether you set a specific locale or keep the default).

The `duration` functionality belongs to the module itself (the 'object' returned by the `require` call). It was designed this way, apparently. The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) states that durations are contextless and, hence, have no defined moment.

To get what you want, you will need to do something like this:

```
moment.duration( 3600000 ).locale('de').humanize(); //eine Stunde
```

The locale will apply only to that call:

```
moment.duration( 3600000 ).humanize(); //an hour
moment.duration( 3600000 ).locale('de').humanize(); //eine Stunde
moment.duration( 3600000 ).humanize(); //an hour
```

Comment: How mantains the format "h [hours] e m [minutes]" with humanize method ?